# Edit length of underline in menu bar HTML

Tags: html

I am creating a menu bar with an underline at the current page however I need help to edit the length of the underline so that the length will the be the length of the text in the menu bar. Need help! Thanks

```css
.title_span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.underline {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: grey 4px solid;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li><span class="underline"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
    </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Note that while I tried to make your code more useful, by converting it into a Snippet so people can see your code in action, and easily copy it to their answers to build upon, I preserved the omission of the closing `</ul>` tag so as to avoid accidentally solving your problem, or changing your posted code. If that missing closing tag is not missing in your code you may wish to correct it.

Comment: isn't length of underline already the length of the text in snippet? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding on the left and right

Add these lines in your `.underline` css code:

```
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
```

You may have to adjust the pixel amounts according to your situation

This should increase the length, but take up more space, hope it helps.

Comment: However it will move the text too

Comment: Try to decrease the margins on all your `li`, this should bring them back together, not sure if thats the best way though.